# Resampling hourly data to daily data and summing over a specific column in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, resampling

I have the data in the format as mentioned in image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vThVe.png) in which hourly consumption rate is mentioned.
[image]
I would like to sum the values of only *Consumption rate* column on a daily basis i.e convert hourly data to daily data.

Using Python's `data.resample('D').sum()` will sum all the numeric columns, but I only want to sum the *Consumption rate* column and merge other columns so that the final output will look as image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDbu0.png).
[image]
How to do this using Python?

Comment: could you please add the example as text - copy&paste is better than OCR... that would help to derive a more meaningful answer.

Comment: @MrFuppes I am unable to add the example as text due to character limit. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: you don't have to add you whole data set, just a [mre]. See also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/10197418). Regarding your question, are you looking for [Pandas df.resample with column-specific aggregation function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44289526/10197418)?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a reproducible example based on your question and have used Pandas built-in [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`resample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and arithmetic functions to obtain the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd

# Generate columns as per example
CustomerID = [152] * 7 + [159] * 6 + [162] * 3

ProductID = ['ABC'] * len(CustomerID)

TankID = ['xyz'] * len(CustomerID)

ConsumptionDateTime = (
    pd.to_datetime(['2018-09-11 13:30:00',
                    '2018-09-11 14:30:00',
                    '2018-09-11 15:30:00',
                    '2018-09-11 21:30:00',
                    '2018-09-12 00:30:00',
                    '2018-09-12 18:30:00',
                    '2018-09-11 19:30:00'])
    )

ConsumptionDateTime = (
    ConsumptionDateTime
    .append(
            pd.date_range(start='2018-09-11 20:30:00',
                  end='2018-09-12 04:30:00',
                  freq='H')
            )
    )


ConsumptionEndTime = (
    pd.to_datetime(['2018-09-11 14:30:00',
                    '2018-09-11 15:30:00',
                    '2018-09-11 21:30:00',
                    '2018-09-11 23:30:00',
                    '2018-09-12 18:30:00',
                    '2018-09-12 19:30:00',
                    '2018-09-11 22:30:00'])
    )

ConsumptionEndTime = (
    ConsumptionEndTime
    .append(
        ConsumptionDateTime[7:] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='H')
        )
    )

ConsumptionRate = [0, 0, 25, 4, 29, 1, 0, 0, 4, 7, 5, 99, 41, 4, 0, 0]

# Create Pandas DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({'CustomerID': CustomerID,
                     'ProductID': ProductID,
                     'TankID': TankID,
                     'ConsumptionDateTime': ConsumptionDateTime,
                     'ConsumptionEndTime': ConsumptionEndTime,
                     'ConsumptionRate': ConsumptionRate})

# Set DateTimeIndex to enable resampling
data.set_index('ConsumptionDateTime', drop=False, inplace=True)

# Group data
grouped_data = data.groupby(['CustomerID', 'ProductID', 'TankID']).resample('D')

# Apply calculations and concatenate results in a single output
final_data = pd.concat([grouped_data['ConsumptionEndTime'].min().dt.date,
                        grouped_data['ConsumptionRate'].sum()],
                       axis=1)
```

Note that I have set the ConsumptionDateTime as the DataFrame index before resampling the data from ~hourly to daily.

The resulting DataFrame looks like the following:

```
                                                ConsumptionEndTime  ConsumptionRate
CustomerID ProductID TankID ConsumptionDateTime                                    
152        ABC       xyz    2018-09-11                  2018-09-11               29
                            2018-09-12                  2018-09-12               30
159        ABC       xyz    2018-09-11                  2018-09-11               16
                            2018-09-12                  2018-09-12              140
162        ABC       xyz    2018-09-12                  2018-09-12                4
```